# How to save pdf output of html2pdf to a folder in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, html2pdf

Using html2pdf plugin, I'm converting a div to pdf and downloading it which is working perfectly fine in browsers.

But when I tried to do the same in Ionic app installed, it's not downloading the file.

```
html2pdf(document.getElementById("orderConfirmation"), {
      margin: 1,
      filename: 'order.pdf',
      image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
      jsPDF: { unit: 'cm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
    }).save();
```

How can I make it work in ionic app as well?

Comment: maybe this link helps https://www.djamware.com/post/5bb6009580aca74669894418/ionic-4-angular-6-and-cordova-export-and-view-pdf-file#ch2

Comment: use this plugin to download file: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer

Comment: @Najamussaqib, This will download from a URL. But I'm building the PDF in browser itself. How can I pass the data to plugin directly instead of URL?